# MacBook Pro restores last user session after shutdown because of low battery

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, security, power, startup

I had only one account on my MBP. I created a new account on it for my son and he has his own password.

I was logged-in with an open session on my account.  I closed the lid and left it there, unplugged.  Eventually it shut down due to a low battery.

My son plugged it in and it restarted.  It asked for his password to login on his account but when he validated the credentials, instead of opening his a new session for him it reconnected him to the last active session; my session on my account.

I have security concerns with how this worked.  I believe macOS should've created a new session matching my son user credentials when it restarted but it didn't.

Is this normal behaviour? How can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: I edited it as the way it was edited previously showed some misunderstanding of my issue

Answer (score 1):

You might not have understood it fully since your lid was closed.  So I will take you to an [adventure](https://sites.google.com/site/si688f11/week-4-attention/group-16) to demonstrate what you would have seen if you left the lid **open** at the time.

### Battery Low (~15%)

Around at 15% when running on battery power, the battery icon in the menu bar will turn red in order to notify you that your battery is starting to get low.

> [image]

### Battery Critically Low (~5%)

If you ignore the initial low battery warning and keep on using DC power, the MacBook will warn you about the *"reserve battery power"* when the battery drops to about 5%.  At this point, you should as soon as possible plug in your laptop into AC power.  Or else, the computer will take its own action soon.

> [image]

### Battery Empty (~0%)

When your battery reaches *"empty"* (around 0%), the computer is forced into sleep mode in order to prevent its memory contents from being destroyed or lost.

> [image]

---

Your MacBook hit the *"empty"* battery level and had gone to sleep to prevent your data from being damaged.  If it did not sleep, then it would just crash-shutdown and all the unsaved data would be mass-lost.  When you plugged in and powered back on, it restored the previous session.

---

UPDATE:

> My son plugged it in and it restarted. It asked for his password to login on his account but when he validated the credentials, instead of opening his a new session for him it reconnected him to the last active session; my session on my account.
>
> Thanks but that doesn't explain why when logged in as user 1 and it goes on sleep, when you go back and plug it, then at the user login prompt you log with user 2 but it opens user 1 session. Huge security issue to me.
>
> Yes multiple times but not with the latest updates. My question was asked in June.

Really?  That's extremely strange.  I've never seen a Macbook doing this before, and different user sessions shouldn't overlap each other.  If this is still happening, then I would like to suggest you to report this to the Apple company.  It seems like you are experiencing a huge security-related issue, so ***please call the Apple company about this immediately.*** It appears like your Mac could not tell the difference between his account and yours.  This is a massive problem, so ***please report this to Apple ASAP!***

---

As more of a Windows user, I will also point out that in Microsoft Windows it functions in a similar method but what displays on the screen is slightly different. On Windows XP, for example, this is how it works:

**Battery Low (~20%)**: At first, the battery indicator in the taskbar becomes less filled - barely filled with its blue juice.

> [image]

**Battery Critically Low (10%)**: When the battery reaches 10%, the indicator gets a red X mark and a notification is triggered, and the system urges the user to either replace the battery or connect to AC power immediately.

> [image]

**Battery Empty (3%)**: On XP, when the battery reaches 3% the computer will hibernate.

> [image]

But as far as I know, neither Windows nor Mac should perform the action you are describing.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't explain why when logged in as use 1 and it goes on sleep, when you go back and plug it, then at the user login prompt you log with user 2 but it opens user 1 session. Huge security issue to me.

Comment: yes multiple times but not with he latest updates. My question was asked in June.

Comment: thanks I will keep you updated here then

Comment: Well it's not really an answer so I will wait some time to see if someone has a better one and if not I will validate yours, promise.

Comment: @NicolasMassart your mac can no longer differentiate the two accounts.

Comment: do you know why?

Comment: @NicolasMassart it's probably because your MacBook is now getting old?  (Or it's possible you and your son had opened the exact same programs around the moment?)

Comment: @NicolasMassart like I said, unless if you and your son had been working around the exact same programs individually, I can't figure out the exact reason at all.  This seems like a very serious bug.  **You must call the manufacturer as soon as possible.**

Comment: did the user who downvoted this think my answer is wrong? please explain.

Comment: I think you're focusing too much on your SE points instead of helping people. Your behaviour is starting to be very annoying, almost aggressive. Please stop.

Comment: Ok. I apologize.